# Merge two dictionaries in Python with the same keys

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I have two dictionaries with exaclty the same keys.
The first dictionary is :

```
 { "key_1" : "AR" ,
   "key_2":"BR" ,
   "key_3" : "CR" }
```

the second is :

```
{ "key_1" : "signinfication of AR" ,
  "key_2":" signinfication of  BR" ,
  "key_3" : " signinfication of  CR" }
```

and I would like to obtain the dictionary below :

```
{"key_1" : {"AR" : "signinfication of AR"} ,
 "key_2" : {"BR" : "signinfication of BR"} ,
 "key_3" : {"CR" : "signinfication of CR"}
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is as simple as a one line *dict comprehension*.

```
>>> {k : {d1[k]  : d2[k]} for k in d1.keys() & d2.keys()}
{
    "key_2": {
        "BR": " signinfication of  BR"
    },
    "key_1": {
        "AR": "signinfication of AR"
    },
    "key_3": {
        "CR": " signinfication of  CR"
    }
}
```

Here, `d1` and `d2` are your two dictionaries. `d1.keys() & d2.keys()` will perform an intersection on the dictionary keys to ensure that iteration is done over keys that exist in both the dictionaries. Here, that is

```
d1.keys() & d2.keys()
{'key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3'}
```

This is good to have in the general sense when you cannot guarantee that both dictionaries have the exact same keys.

---

On python2.7 and older, you'd need a slight modification, because `keys()` returns  a list. Use `set.intersection` -

```
>>> {k : {d1[k]  : d2[k]} for k in set(d1.keys()).intersection(d2.keys())}
```

---

If you're working with dicts of lists, then the code above requires a `zip`ping between corresponding lists -

```
>>> d1
{
    "key_1": [
        "AR",
        "BR",
        "CR"
    ],
    ...
}    
>>> d2
{
    "key_1": [
        "signfication of AR",
        "signfication of BR",
        "signfication of  CR"
    ],
    ...
}
```

```
>>> {k : dict(zip(d1[k], d2[k])) for k in d1.keys() & d2.keys()}
{
    "key_1": {
        "BR": "signfication of BR",
        "CR": "signfication of  CR",
        "AR": "signfication of AR"
    },
    "key_3": {
        "CE": " signfication of CE",
        "AE": "signfication of AE",
        "BE": " signfication of BE"
    },
    "key_2": {
        "BZ": "signfication of BZ",
        "CZ": "signfication of CZ",
        "AZ": "signfication of AZ"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) together the dictionaries `items()`, and merge them together:

```
d1 = {"key_1" : "AR",
      "key_2":"BR",
      "key_3" : "CR"}

d2 = {"key_1" : "signinfication of AR",
      "key_2":" signinfication of  BR",
      "key_3" : " signinfication of  CR"}

# make sure both lists have same ordered keys
l1 = sorted(d1.items())
l2 = sorted(d2.items())

d = {k1 : {v1:v2} for (k1, v1), (_, v2) in zip(l1, l2)}

print(d)
```

Which outputs:

```
{'key_1': {'AR': 'signinfication of AR'}, 
 'key_2': {'BR': ' signinfication of  BR'}, 
 'key_3': {'CR': ' signinfication of  CR'}}
```

**EDIT:**

As @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ recommended, you can call [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sorted) on the lists before zipping them, which ensures that both dictionaries have the same order: `key_1`, `key_2`, `key_3`. You could also do a preliminary check of the keys, such as checking their intersection, to ensure that both dictionaries have the same keys.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the keys are returned from both dicts in the same order?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ hmm I didn't think of that, sorry. I guess the OP could just use your recommendation in your answer to make sure this happens. I'll add this anyways, thanks.

Comment: It's not a big deal to guarantee that, just call `sorted` and it _should_ work. Upvoted, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
s = { "key_1" : "AR" ,
 "key_2":"BR" ,
 "key_3" : "CR" }

d = { "key_1" : "signinfication of AR" ,
 "key_2":" signinfication of  BR" ,
 "key_3" : " signinfication of  CR" }
new_d = {a:{b:d[a]} for a, b in s.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'key_1': {'AR': 'signinfication of AR'}, 'key_3': {'CR': ' signinfication of  CR'}, 'key_2': {'BR': ' signinfication of  BR'}}
```